# Replace 2 spaces by 1 space in all values of a column

Tags: oracle

I need to replace 2 spaces by only 1 space for all entries of 1 column in an Oracle database. I found [this](http://oracle.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/oracle-sql-l/how-to-replace-mutiple-spaces-in-the-string-with-single-space-in-oracle-3760075) and tried it:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('MODEL', '[[:space:]]{2,}', ' ') new_string
FROM ops.TBL_PRODUCT_DEIN_DESIGN;
```

`MODEL` is the column name. But it has not replaced the double spaces.

How to use that solution or what could be an alternative?

Comment: well I don't think you need a regular expression here, just try : `REPLACE('MODEL','   ', ' ')`   ;)  (note, 2 spaces in quotes, and 1 space, the editor mucks it up a bit)

Comment: @Ditto: Unless you think there may be more to this problem, I can't see a reason why you shouldn't post your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: what is the result of your query?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a regular expression for that. Instead, you could use the replace function in SQL like this:

```
replace(MODEL, '  ', ' ')
```

where `MODEL` is your column, `'  '` is the character(s) that you want to replace and `' '` is the character(s) you want to replace with.